# How to read multiple languages using tesserocr?

Tags: python, image, pdf, anaconda, ocr

I wondered how to read text from image with text on several languages and I found out that it was possible using tesserocr's function  file_to_text, but for some reasons I get an error `TypeError: Expected bytes, got PpmImageFile`. Is there another way to read from image that contains several languages text? Or is there a way to convert PpmImage to bytes?

my code:

```
images = convert_from_path("c.pdf",500,poppler_path=r"C:\Users\aleks\Downloads\poppler-0.68.0_x86\poppler-0.68.0\bin",first_page=260,last_page=265)
final_text = ""
for pg,img in enumerate(images):
   print(tesserocr.file_to_text(img,lang="eng+rus_tra"))
```

Comment: I know how to set a language for pytesseract, but I don't know how to set a languegae for tesserocr (pytesseract doesn't suit me because it can't read multiple languages from the same picture).

Comment: Ok, I will try, but what should I do with ```TypeError: Expected bytes, got PpmImageFile``` error?